# Solr filter out facet results individually

Tags: java, search, solr, faceted-search

I am working on filtering out facet returned by solr based on predefined list of criterias.

For example I am querying for documents that are of different types. The facet returned is as follows:

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
  <lst name="facet_queries"/>
  <lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="applicationName">
      <int name="microsoft">2304</int>
      <int name="word">2277</int>
      <int name="0">1550</int>
      <int name="office">598</int>
      <int name="8">471</int>
      <int name="9">446</int>
      <int name="90">445</int>
      <int name="10">435</int>
      <int name="100">426</int>
      <int name="9.0">418</int>
      <int name="10.0">411</int>
      <int name="8.0">375</int>
      <int name="80">375</int>
      <int name="2">328</int>
      <int name="5">308</int>
      <int name="acrobat">272</int>
```

Lets say I want not show microsoft as a result for this facet_field. The query currently looked like the following. I have give some try with Tag and exclusion filters but im out of luck...

```
q=*%3A*&wt=xml&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=applicationName
```

EDIT My current solution was to add a custom search handler and perform the filtering post-query execution. I would like to have a solution through the query mechanism this way would involve less processing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever tried the "facet.query" parameter? If I have understood your problem correctly, if you put a facet.query=-applicationName:microsoft on your request, Solr will do exactly what you want. So, it should be like:

> q=*%3A*&facet=true&facet.field=applicationName&facet.query=-applicationName:microsoft

---

EDIT:
The above hint is wrong. It will only return the number of documents that don't have "microsoft" on the field "applicationName".

You should put the same query on your "q" parameter. Just like that:

> q=-applicationName:microsoft&facet=true&facet.field=applicationName

Comment: You can specify the facet.query parameter multiple times to use multiple queries as separate facet constraints.

Comment: Hi, I have just attempted it and this is the result:`<lst name="facet_counts"><lst name="facet_queries"><int name="-applicationName:microsoft">382</int></lst><lst name="facet_fields"><lst name="applicationName"><int name="word">424</int><int name="microsoft">367</int><int name="0">277</int>`

Comment: This would have been nice but the negation is not working as expected.

Comment: The above hint is wrong. It will only return the number of documents that don't have "microsoft" on the field "applicationName".

You should put the same query on your "q" parameter. Just like that:

q=-applicationName:microsoft&facet=true&facet.field=applicationName